# SELECT between dynamically queried rows

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, range

Let's say I have a book table:

```
CREATE TABLE book (
    -- NOTE: the app guarantees that content is ordered by id
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    section TEXT NOT NULL,
    verse INTEGER NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO book (id, section, verse, content) VALUES
    (0, "Prelude", 0, "A long long time ago"),
    (1, "Prelude", 1, "I can still remember"),
    (2, "Chap",    0, "Something happened"),
    (3, "Chap",    1, "Something else happened"),
    (4, "Chap",    2, "A weighty climax"),
    (5, "End",     0, "The end")
;
```

I want to be able to query for all verses with within a starting verse and chapter with only one SQL query. I can do that with the following SQL:

```
SELECT id, content
FROM book
WHERE
    id BETWEEN
        (SELECT id FROM book WHERE section == "Prelude" AND verse == 1 LIMIT 1)
    AND
        (SELECT id FROM book WHERE section == "Chap" AND verse == 2 LIMIT 1)
```

---

```
λ sqlite3 :memory: < tmp.sql
id          content
----------  --------------------
1           I can still remember
2           Something happened
3           Something else happe
4           A weighty climax
```

That involves 2 subqueries, and I'm not sure it's the best way. Can I improve this query to not have the subqueries (with the idea that fewer subqueries are more efficient)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code after the `BETWEEN` clause is scanning twice the table to return the 2 ids.
 But also there is another problem: 
do you know in advance which id is the smallest and which is the highest? 
If not (probably) then you can't safely set each of the returned ids before or after `AND`.
For example if you do this:

```
id BETWEEN
    (SELECT id FROM book WHERE section == "Chap" AND verse == 2 LIMIT 1)
AND
    (SELECT id FROM book WHERE section == "Prelude" AND verse == 1 LIMIT 1)
```

nothing will be returned.
So you must set the min id as the lower bound and the max id as the upper bound.

Use a [CTE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) so the table will be scanned only once to get the starting and ending ids:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT MIN(id) AS fromId, MAX(id) AS toId FROM book 
  WHERE (section = "Prelude" AND verse = 1) OR (section = "Chap" AND verse = 2)
)
SELECT id, content
FROM book
WHERE id BETWEEN (SELECT fromId FROM cte) AND (SELECT toId FROM cte)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9SJYoJ3UDjgY7ugCd3nweA/1).
Or with a CROSS JOIN with the CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT MIN(id) AS fromId, MAX(id) AS toId FROM book 
  WHERE (section = "Prelude" AND verse = 1) OR (section = "Chap" AND verse = 2)
)
SELECT b.id, b.content
FROM book AS b CROSS JOIN cte AS c
WHERE b.id BETWEEN c.fromId AND c.toId
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9SJYoJ3UDjgY7ugCd3nweA/3).
Results:

```
| id  | content                 |
| --- | ----------------------- |
| 1   | I can still remember    |
| 2   | Something happened      |
| 3   | Something else happened |
| 4   | A weighty climax        |
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is fine (although it might not be exactly how I would write it).  What you want for performance is an index on `book(section, verse)`:

```
create index idx_book_section_verse on book(section, verse);
```

With such an index, I would probably move the conditions to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT b.id, b.content
FROM book b CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT id
      FROM book
      WHERE section = 'Prelude' AND verse = 1 
     ) id1 CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT id
      FROM book
      WHERE section = 'Chap' AND verse = 2 
     ) id2
WHERE b.id BETWEEN id1.id AND id2.id;
```

Each subquery in this form (or in yours) is really just "dipping" into the index to fetch one value.  That's pretty fast.  Then the `WHERE` clause is filtering on a primary key, which is also fast.

Comment: *... just "dipping..."* twice though. The question is how to avoid this.

Comment: @forpas . . . Not really.  An index lookup is very fast.  No need to optimize it, at least not if you are planning on using a database.

Comment: Not really what? The (fast) index look up will happen **twice**. The question is how to avoid this.

Comment: @forpas . . . Good luck.  Anyone who works with databases and care about performance would be happy with two index lookups and a scan on a primary key.  That is definitely better than a full table scan, which is why this answer focuses on having the appropriate index for the query.

Comment: Anyone who works with databases and care about performance would be happier with just 1 index lookup and this is the question.